# Unable to load one or more breakpoints error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

My Visual Studio is behaving strangely. I have no breakpoints in my projects but whenever I start Visual Studio, an error message comes up showing that it's unable to load one or more breakpoints. Secondly, I have 10 projects in my solution - I set one as a startup project but Visual studio is not saving this information.
I have to set it every time I open the solution.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Re the breakpoint problem: Have you debugged into assembler? You might have accidentally set a breakpoint on some assembler instruction. Look into the breakpoint list (Debug->Windows->Breakpoints; it's Alt+F9 for me) to see which breakpoints are set for the solution. Of course, source and binary not matching might also cause this. Alternatively the following might help, too.

Re the startup project: Visual Studio saves all user-specific data regarding a solution in a `*.suo` file which it puts right beside the `*.sln` file. This might have gotten corrupted (although I've never seen this). Try to delete it and see whether this helps. 
On a second thought, both problems might be caused by someone having checked in the `*.suo` file located in a hidden `.vs` directory. Have you checked this?

Comment: Deleting the solution .suo file fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for deleting the .suo - in my case it had become corrupted after a BSOD and this was producing the breakpoint error

Comment: +1 for me too with deleting the .suo. I also had a BSOD in Win8 which might producint this error.

Comment: Deleting the solution .suo file fixed it for me too. Thanks.

Comment: @SebaIllingworth How do i delete and rebuild my solution file?

Comment: @Pomster: You do not delete your solution (`.sln`) file, but the user-specifc settings (`.suo`) file. As to how you do this... Have you tried the Windows Explorer? (You might want to try [Super User](http://superuser.com) if you need help to delete a file. `:-/`) The `.suo` file is (re)created automagically if there's no existing one.

Comment: i am not looking any *.suo file beside solution

Comment: @Nitu: Since this file is recreated every time you open the solution, and since it is where the breakpoints are stored, it is there. Maybe you could search for it? Again, if you have trouble navigating the file system you would need to ask at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: The .suo file is hidden so you'll need to enable hidden files to see it.

Comment: Yes the .suo is hidden and it will create automatically. It wont impact any other changes to your code. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: It is in the hidden ".vs" directory (VS2015)

Comment: Same symptoms with VS 2017 15.8.5: "Unable to load one or more breakpoints" plus startup project reset. Deleting .vso fixed it.

Comment: It does not work for me. Verified in VS 2017 15.9.21

Comment: @RDeveloper: This answer is more than 10 ears old. I haven't used VS for almost a decade. I'd be surprised if things haven't changed.

Answer (score 10):

I also encountered such a problem, the solutions is delete the *.suo file in the solution directory.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to delete all breakpoints but every time I opened the project this message appeared.

I have found a hidden directory inside the solution: ".vs"

I renamed it to something else and re-opened the solution - the message disappeared.

Comment: Bingo！ I have the same problem even I deleted the .pdb file in Debug directory.  After I renamed .vs directory, the phenomenon disappeared.

Comment: Please don't rename, but rather delete that folder... VS will autoregenerate it. There is nothing but cache type of stuff in there.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete ".vs" folder and reload the solution

Comment: Yeah its working in VS 2019. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I cleaned the solution from BUILD>CLEAN SOLUTION and rebuilt the solution and it resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting *.suo file worked for me

Comment: Please add further information when providing an answer to a question so that the OP and any future readers can best use the information.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us more information on why Visual Studio can't load the break point?  If you hover over the breakpoint icon it should provide a tooltip message saying why the breakpoint is unable to load.

The most common reason for this is a mismatch between the source file and the binary you are debugging.  It can happen if you F5 with build errors for instance.  Or F5 against a deployed DLL after you have changed the source for the DLL.  Try rebuilding and potentially redeploying as appropriate and see if that helps your problem.

As for the startup information.  Try updating it, hitting save all and restarting Visual Studio.  That should ensure the information is saved.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an breakpoint that disappered (but how?). Please try Ctrl+Shift+F9 to 'Delete All Breakpoints' (VS2008).

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Shift+F9 to 'Delete All Breakpoints' does not work.

Delete everything in your project which is not your source code: "obj" and "bin" sub-directories, all *.user and *.suo also from the hidden ".vs" directory.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `.suo` file did not work for me, neither did deleting `obj` folder. Only thing that worked was deleting everything from hidden `.vs` folder (I moved the files somewhere else on my machine first to make sure I could move them back in case of an error)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue with Visual Studio 2012 RC. I fixed it by setting a arbitrary breakpoint and then deleting it in the Debug->Windows->Breakpoint window.

Comment: Just got it again. AFAIK, a VS corruption occurred when Flash in FireFox crashed and (because of?) windows explorer crashed (W8 RC) thus corrupting VS. While the above procedure fixed breakpoint errors, I could not get a StartUp project to set until I reset VS studio and erased the hidden *.suo file(s).